# How to pass by value where a pass by reference is requierd

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I need to pass an object by value and i don't want to change the function cause it maybe called in other paths and works properly for their needs but this certain path needs to be passed by value.

for example the function is:

```
public function storeInDB(&$data) {
 ...
//adding data to table in db
...
}
```

And i want to pass $data and after that i would immediately change the $data like calling the above function in a loop:

```
var $items->order_id = $this->getOrderId();
foreach($products as $product){
                $items->product_id = $product['id'];
                $testItems->storeInDB($items);
            }
```

the problem is the $data changes and i only get 1 row in my table which expected to be `count($products)`.

Comment: I don't think `var $items->order_id` is valid syntax

Comment: Also, "objects" are not values in PHP5, and are always manipulated through references (pointers to objects). `$items` and `$data` are references, not objects. Even if you pass references by value, you would have two references pointing to the same object and they can modify that same object. So I don't think pass-by-value is your issue. In fact, if `$data` is not assigned to inside `storeInDB()` (i.e. `$data = ...`), there is no difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference.